# What low heat, energy efficient light bulbs can fit my adjustable IKEA November Lamp?

Tags: light-bulb

IKEA discontinued this NOVEMBER lamp in 2007, but I still use it. As you can see below, it uses a bizarrely shaped light bulb that heats up WAY TOO MUCH! It warms me up too!

Can this lamp accept low heat, energy saving light bulbs? I asked two home improvement store employees, but they did not know.

[image] [image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

[image]

Comment: You're missing a key point of information: bulbs have "base type" codes.  MR16, E26, F32T8, G9, etc.  You need to identify the base type used by that fixture.  Look for markings on the fixture or in its manual. Or at the packages for replacement bulbs. Once you have the base type, it's downhill from there, the word for efficient bulbs is "LED".

Comment: One more consideration: it's hard to tell exactly from your photo but the bulb looks to be very close to the back of the reflector. For that size bulb, LED replacements tend to be a bit larger, particularly in diameter. If the bulb is currently right up against the reflector, there may not be enough space for an LED replacement. On the other hand, if you've got 10mm of space or more, you're probably OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a 120V G9 halogen. You can get LED replacement bulbs, they look like this:

[image]

However... I'm not sure you'll get good results. G9 lightbulbs are really tiny, there is no room for a capacitor, which means they usually flicker at twice AC line frequency, which is damn annoying. So, try to get a bulb that says **"Flicker-free"**.

Personally I would screw a GU10 socket in the center of the reflector and use a 3000K 90CRI 60° GU10 [bulb](https://www.lampesdirect.fr/philips-ledspot-mv-value-gu10-3-7w-930-60d-master-meilleur-rendu-des-couleurs-blanc-chaud-dimmable-substitut-35w).

Comment: capacitors come in the same size of package (most any SMD size) as the LEDs themselves, don't count them out.

Answer (score 3):

It's a G9 - you can read it on the label inside the shade.

[image]

Google 'G9 LED bulb' for a modern low-energy replacement, or see these examples from [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=G9%20LED%20bulb&crid=142YMTHLHC3M3&sprefix=g9%20led%20bulb%2Caps%2C135&ref=nb_sb_noss_1)